# LaTex - how to create boxes with fixed heights and widths, with enclosed text that is vertically and horizontally aligned?

Tags: latex, tex

This is for creating flashcards in LaTeX. My printer doesn't support duplex printing - which packages like flashcards and flacards seem to require - so I am trying to create a two-column arrangement as follows on each page:

[Col1: Front side of the card] [Col2: Back side of the card]

Each row would correspond to a single flashcard. The plan is to cut each row up, fold them along the middle and staple them to create a "card".

The question: how best can I create a single box with a specified height and width, and with the text in it aligned vertically?

I am relatively new to Latex, so this cripples my options. I don't need full, detailed answers necessarily - any pointers at all in the right direction would help immensely! Any suggestions on alternative methods to achieve what I'm shooting for would also be helpful.

Many thanks!

Comment: shouldn't this be moved to tex.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Suppose you want to create the box of 40pt height and 3cm width:

```
\vbox to 40pt {\vfil
\hbox to 3cm{Some info}%
\vfil
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it.  It will be easier when laying out the page if you put all margins to 0pt.

Comment: Thank you. 

However, I did manage to get a result I wanted through tables, but will revisit this arrangement soon.

Comment: For any other newbs like me who want to use this to place a centered equation in the middle of the box, let me save you several hours: Replace `{Some info}` with `{\fil \ensuremath{Some eqn} \hfil}`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use whatever packages to make your flashcards, and then save the output in pdf format (use `pdflatex` for example).  Then, make another document in Latex which uses [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/) package and uses its `nup` option to print two pages per page.  Pdfpages has a lot of options, to fine-tune the page layout. That gives you all the power of the other packages for your use.

Answer (score 1):

My [**TikZ**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)-based solution with two `scope`s and nested `fbox` and `parbox`: text is horizontally (due to `\centering`) and vertically centered in the two boxes/columns, widths and heights may all be tuned.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,multi=false,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
  \node (0,0) {\fbox{\parbox[c][100mm][c]{65mm}{\centering%
    \lipsum[1]
  }}};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=75mm]
  \node (0,0) {\fbox{\parbox[c][120mm][c]{65mm}{\centering%
    Some text\\%
    \ \\%
    \lipsum[2]
  }}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]